# PHP se cruzan las sesiones

Tags: php

Tengo una aplicación de gestión en PHP 7 la que acceden varios usuarios a la vez.
Todas las páginas pasan por un único fichero Cabecera.php que inicia la sesión con session_start();

El problema es que cuando dos usuarios piden la misma pagina a la vez parece que el servidor envía la misma página a los dos usuarios, viéndose en ambos navegadores la misma información de uno de los dos usuarios.
Presenta a los dos las mismas variables de sesión, incluso presenta a ambos el mismo valor de $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] lo que ya me resulta increíble.
Los usuarios están en redes diferentes, es decir que su IP pública no es la misma.

Cuando el usuario que ha recibido la información errónea, pincha en cualquier opción de la aplicación, los datos vuelven a ser los correctos.
¿alguna idea?

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once("./funciones.php"); 

$Perfil = 0;
$Nombre="";
$IdUsuario=0;

if (isset($_SESSION["ID_USUARIO"]) )  { $IdUsuario  = $_SESSION["ID_USUARIO"]; }
if (isset($_SESSION["NOMBRE"]) )      { $Nombre     = $_SESSION["NOMBRE"]; }
if (isset($_SESSION["PERFIL"]) )      { $Perfil     = $_SESSION["PERFIL"]; }

?>

<body>
<div  id="Usuario"> Conectado: 
<?php echo $Nombre . " -> " . $DSPerfil . " " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];  ?>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Para poder ayudar necesitaríamos ver el fichero de Cabecera.php

Comment: ¿Es posible que en funciones.php, después de iniciar la sesión cambies sus variables a partir de una base de datos con algún error en la consulta? Te sugiero que pongas `<?php echo $Nombre . " - SessionID: " . session_id() . " -> " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];  ?>` para ver si el id de sesión también es el mismo

Comment: No, en funciones.php no se accede a las variables de session.   He probado con  cookies ( que deberían de estar en el pc local ) y tampoco va.  Parece  que el servidor procesa la pagina y al enviar al navegador, se la envía al otro usuario.  El sesision_id() tambien lo cambia

Comment: 1) Si el `session_id()` es diferente, es que la sesión es diferente para el servidor. 2) Pones `isset($_SESSION["ID_USUARIO"])`. Entonces, ¿dónde le das el valor de ID_USUARIO? Entiendo que será en un login o algo así. Es que es ahí, donde asignas valores a esas `$_SESSION['XXXXXXX']` donde me imagino que está el error. Especialmente si `session_id()` varía para cada uno

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema, he accedido con sesion_name() diferentes, le paso distintas Variable por $_SESSION pero al acceder a la vez la vez a la misma pagina desde distinto PCs/ Navegadores etc.. se siguen solapando los usuarios.. y en uno puedo ver el otro

Comment: Yo solucione el problema añadiendo a todas las urls &idUsuario=xxxx, donde xxxx es el id de cada usuario, de esta forma aunque dos usuarios vayan a la misma página en el mismo instante, como la url son diferentes, le da a cada uno lo suyo.  Es un poco chapuza, pero se sale del paso